# How to load JS file in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am new to Angular. I have added JS files in **angular-cli.json** inside **scripts** tag. Files are loaded successfully but the problem is that on my LoginForm console showing:

> zone.js:192 Uncaught ReferenceError: theWYSIWYG is not defined

it is loaded when I loggedIn successfully I route to my another component from `login-form.component.ts` `this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);` on dashboard component some of html code is

```
<div id="theWYSIWYG" name="theWYSIWYG" frameborder="0" contentEditable="true"  dir="rtl" ></div>
```

function defined inside the js file which is loaded when app was started. Why JS is not accessing dashboard components.?

Comment: in `tsconfig.json`, do you have `"allowJs": true` under `compilerOptions`. This will allow typescript compiler to resolve the references to .js files.

Comment: becasuse your `.js` file execute before your component initilize. so before accessing element with id `theWYSIWYG` add condition for undefinded.

Comment: Yes! It is true.

Comment: When app starts all js are loaded first and it is through an console error that id=xyz not defined. while it is already defined in second component's html file.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use javascript in your component. you must be included before @Component

```
    declare var require: any;
    const myFunc = require('../assets/jsFile');
    @Component({ ....
```

and then inside your AppComponent you can call javascript function with myFunc .

```
ngOnInit() {
  myFunc.func1();
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use these functions in component. I have js files in which all functions are already defined. But problem is that all JS are loads when app starts. At this time it does not see html file which is in another component (at this moment JS through error id=xyz is undefined while it is defined in 2nd component html file). but WHY?

Comment: What do you mean by this text ?" it is defined in 2nd component HTML file"

Comment: I have created 2components 1st named "LoginForm" and 2nd name "Dashboard" in this component I have dashboard.component.html. In which all these ids are.

Answer (score 0):

`import * as _ from "<jsfile_name>";` you can import js file in your component type script file